# How to share application data to whatsapp friends??

Tags: android, share, whatsapp

I am developing an android application in which I want to share my data through WhatsApp and hike(to my friends in phone contact) or mail to my friends.

Can someone please explain me with lines of codes...

Comment: This is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most social Android apps, WhatsApp listens to intents to share media and text. Simply create an intent to share text, for example :

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

startActivity(sendIntent);
```